# The sequence in which every symbol minimizes conditional complexity?

Tags: computability, randomness

I formulate the question in terms of universal distributions. Fix a version of Solomonoff's universal distribution $\mathbf M$ and consider the following procedure for generating an infinite binary sequence $\omega$.

Start with some $\omega_0$. Each subsequent element is given by $\omega_n=\arg \max_a\mathbf M(a|\omega_{1:n-1})$.

What are the properties of $\omega$? For example, is it necessarily computable? Does the answer depend on the choice of $\mathbf M$?

The equivalent formulation is the following but it does not really help me advance with the problem.

Is there a universal lower semicomputable $\lambda$-supermartingale $t$ and a binary sequence $\tilde\omega$ such that $t$ always "goes up" along $\tilde\omega$ but never succeeds?

This type of problem arises when a player plays against a reactive environment and the sequence the player observes is not exogenous. A more general question is what is the short-run behavior of $\mathbf M$ since asymptotic results do not seem to help here.

**UPDATE**

As an example, consider a simple coordination game with payoff matrix:

(1,1)     (0,0)

(0,0)     (1,1)

Consider two players who infinitely repeatedly play this game. Their goal is to maximize the payoff. Assume that the player are myopic that is they care only about the payoff in the current period.

Each player observes his opponent's history and tries to match him. Each player has a prior distribution about his opponent's play and updates it using Bayes's rule.

Now assume that the prior distribution is Solomonoff's $\mathbf M$. Then every period a player chooses an action $\arg \max_a\mathbf M(a|\omega_{1:n-1})$ where $\omega_{1:n-1}$ is the opponent's history. The other player does the same, thus the rule $\omega_n=\arg \max_a\mathbf M(a|\omega_{1:n-1})$.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? There are many notions I don't recognise so you may be a ways into the rabbit hole. Show us the way!

Comment: @Raphael, I added some context, let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: I notice that this has not been answered for a while. Have you got an answer somewhere else? Have you considered (re)posting to [math.SE] or [cstheory.SE]?

Comment: I [posted on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/what-kind-of-string-is-produced-by-successive-application-of-argmax-m). No responses though.